# Using regex and sed to replace a string inside of a file

Tags: regex, linux

Having the following string inside of a text file.

> {"_job":"delete","query":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"_id":"28381"}}],"should":[]}}},"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.meta='This
>   is a ' test string Peedr'"},"timestamp":1518165383,"host":"","port":"9200","index":"","docType":"","customIndexer":""}

I would like to replace all the `'` that are inside the `ctx._source.meta=''` part with `\'` **using sed**.

In the example above I've `This is a ' test string Peedr` which I would like to convert to `This is a \' test string Peedr`, so the desired output would be:

> {"_job":"delete","query":{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"_id":"28381"}}],"should":[]}}},"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.meta='This
>   is a \' test string 
>   Peedr'"},"timestamp":1518165383,"host":"","port":"9200","index":"","docType":"","customIndexer":""}

I'm using the following regex to get the `'` that is inside the `ctx._source.meta` string (3rd capture group).

```
(meta=')(.*?)(')(.*?)(')
```

I've the regex, but I dont know how to use the `sed` comand in order to *replace the 3rd capture group with `\'`*.

Can someone give me a hand and tell me the `sed` comand I have to use?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure there would be only one unescaped single quote there?

Comment: Yes, only one, revo.

Comment: and is it there always?

Comment: yes, there's always one.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` generally does not support the Perl regex extensions, so the non-greedy `.*?` will probably not do what you hope.  If you want to use Perl regex, use Perl!

```
perl -pe "s/(meta='.*?)(')(.*?')/\$1\\\\\$2\$3/"
```

This will still not necessarily work if the input is malformed; a better approach would be to specifically exclude single quotes from the match, and then you don't need the non-greedy matching.

```
sed "s/\\(meta='[^']*\\)'\\([^']*'\\)/\\1\\\\'\\2/"
```

In both cases, the number of backslashes required to escape the backslashes inside the shell's double quotes is staggering.

Answer (score 0):

You put back-references to groups except one you want to replace. There is a better way to accomplish same task:

```
sed -E "s/(ctx\._source\.meta=')([^']*)(')([^']*')/\1\2\\'\4/"
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work (any of the two solutions) with the given example. The command outputs the same without changing the `'` to `\'`. Thanks in advance, revo.

Comment: The use of `sed -E` is not portable. Perhaps refactor this to a POSIX-compliant regex instead.  The non-greedy regex is *definitely* not portable; which version of `sed` do you hope would support this PCRE construct? (The error is probably the OP's but still.)

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean it's not portable?

Comment: If it doesn't work then it means your input string is not exactly the same as in your question. Please show what you do. @Avión

Comment: I take the string of the post, put it into a file titled `test.txt` and then run `sed -E "s/(ctx\._source\.meta=')([^']*)(')([^']*')/\1\2\\'\4/" test.txt`

Comment: Scripts which work on one host but fail on another are not portable. `sed` is standardized in POSIX and you can reasonably expect any reasonable platform to support the standard, but `-E` is not in that standard.

Comment: @tripleee *Historically this was a GNU extension, but the -E extension has since been added to the POSIX standard (http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528), so use -E for portability. GNU sed has accepted -E as an undocumented option for years, and \*BSD seds have accepted -E for years as well*

Comment: I stand corrected. You still see people complaining from time to time here on Stack Overflow that scripts with `-E` don't work for them; but let's just have them upgrade to a recent enough POSIX `sed` then.  The lack of support for `.*?` is still an issue.

Comment: That may be true but in question OP is using a POSIX ERE syntax which works for them and he or she is trying to deal with capturing groups only. So I assumed `-E` in first place since it enables use of ERE syntax. @tripleee

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with my build, I missed the point about ungreediness but doing so didn't result in an unexpected output. You are %100 right about this one, going to remove it. @tripleee

Comment: But non-greedy matching is not ERE syntax. It's not clear that the OP actually successfully matched this regex in `sed` specifically; a common beginner assumption is that there is a single regex dialect and exactly the same expression will work in `grep`, `sed`, Python, JavaScript, their favorite editor, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You may use:

```
sed "s/ ' / \\\' /g" sample.txt
```

- The first part will instruct `sed` to only look for a single quote between 2 spaces, as such `ctx._source.meta='This` and `string Peedr'"}` will not match, hence will not be changed.

Edit:

At the poster's request, I edited my `sed` command to apply to extra use cases:

`sed "s/\(ctx._source.meta='.*\)'\(.*Peedr'\"\)/\1\\\'\2/g"`

Comment: This would replace the `'` of the `ctx._source.meta` itself. I want to replace only what is inside that tag.

Comment: Please try it beforehand and you'll see it only replaces the `'` in `ctx._source.meta='This is a ' test string `

Comment: This works with `This is a ' test string` but it doesnt work with `This is a' test string`, `This is a 'test string` or `This is a'test string`. Can you make it work with that examples to? The solution must look for `the ' that are inside the meta tag`, not `for the ' that are between two spaces`. Thanks again!